# TypeError on importing dict to dataframe

Tags: xml, pandas, lxml, stringio

Any tips on importing lxml.etree start event into pandas.DataFrame.   The following code shows simple lxml parsing and converting entries into dataframe (pandas) using from_records.  [NOTE: I tried from_dict but it needed a list per attribute while from_records seems to handle dictionaries better. ]

The pd.DataFrame.from_record fails on coercion of data attributes... with error:

```
TypeError: Argument must be bytes or unicode, got 'int'
```

Thanks in advance for any tips?

CODE SNIPPET:

```
x2="""<m2>
  <entry attrm201=1 attrm202 attrm203=1>m0201_t</entry>
  <entry attrm201=1 attrm0203=1>m0202_t</entry>
  <entry displevel=1 entrytype=1>m0202_t</entry>
</m2>"""

import pandas as pd
objDF = pd.DataFrame()

import io
srcIO = io.StringIO(x2)
#srcIO = io.BytesIO(str.encode(x2))


from lxml import etree
for event, e in etree.iterparse(srcIO, recover=True, html=True, events=('start', 'end')):
    if event != 'start' : continue
    if e.tag != 'entry' : continue
    elmDict = e.attrib
    elmDict[e.tag] = e.text 
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(elmDict, index=[0])
    objDF = pd.concat([objDF, df])
    print(event, objDF)
```

UPDATE #1 - Work around

Replacing the Dataframe.from_record with list (ie. basic  Dataframe) seems to do the trick.  The trick is to extract the values from the dict into an list and the keys into a list... then pd.DataFrame is able to marshal the dtypes.  Yet, I am not sure why from_records isn't working? (sorry don't have time to dig into the code). Below is the code that works...

```
# from_record doesn't work 
#df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(elmDict, index=[0])

# 
arr = []
arr.append(elmDict.values())
df = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=elmDict.keys())
objDF = pd.concat([objDF, df])
```

Comment: I added UPDATE #1.   This provides a work around of importing a dict into a dataframe along axis 1 (rows).    The problem seems to be that dict has the values as strings, e.g. '1', and the coercing  to int gets confused.   I'll leve it open in case someone may know more details.

Comment: Your UPDATE section should be an answer since it isn't part of the question but a way to answer the question. Your question will still be considered open as long as it has no *accepted answer*